# How to scrape tweets containing a specific link using twitter API in python?

Tags: python, url, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy library to retrieve tweets containing specific link but it doesn't return anything.

Here is the code :

```
####input your credentials here
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='www.democracynow.org/2018/4/18/americas_1_weapons_salesman_trump_promotes', count=10,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

I tried the normal link and the encoded one but both didn't work. There is no error, it's just empty.

Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

If you perform [a search on Twitter's website for your query](https://twitter.com/search?q=www.democracynow.org%2F2018%2F4%2F18%2Famericas_1_weapons_salesman_trump_promotes), you'll see that there are no results.
Instead, you're probably wanting to search for `"https://www.democracynow.org/2018/4/18/americas_1_weapons_salesman_trump_promotes"`.

However, note that Twitter's [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) has a limit of 7 days, and all the results for that search are much older than that. You'll have to use the premium or enterprise search APIs for older results.